# is there an way to ignore signals signature?

Tags: c++, gtk3

I'm trying to connect some widgets with the same user_function callback. In some cases, the signal has diferent signatures.

Searching i found gtk_signal_connect_full, I think.

My Code for example:

```
int MyObject::connect()
{
    callback_object ....

    // Create the callback
    int ret = g_signal_connect(instance, "clicked", G_CALLBACK (connect_callback), callback_object);
    int ret = g_signal_connect(instance, "button-release-event", G_CALLBACK (connect_callback), callback_object);

    // Return handler id
    return ret;
}

void MyObject::connect_callback(GObject *passedInstance, gpointer param1, gpointer param2)
{
    // Return to st_callback
    struct st_callback *callback_object = (struct st_callback *) param2;
    if(sizeof(param1) == 0) {
        callback_object = (struct st_callback *) param1;
    }

}
```

Can i "abstract" user_function like that? and if I can, How to get extra parameters like GdkEvent or GdkEventButton, or gchar, ...

EDIT
- This question is a GTK+ issue, because in the first g_signal_connect, param1 is my struct. I'ts ok, I know my struct to cast back. In the second g_signal_connect, param1 is a GdkEventButton. It's OK too, becouse I know it's a GdkEventButton to cast back. BUT, how to do this, if I dont know param1 is my struct, if its a GdkEvent, GdkEventButton, gchar, or all others possibilities of sinal signatures?

EDIT 2
- I have found this info on [Closures doc](https://developer.gnome.org/gobject/stable/gobject-Closures.html#g-cclosure-marshal-generic)

> Closures allow the callee to get the types of the callback parameters, which means that language bindings don't have to write individual glue for each callback type.

This seen perfect for what i'm looking for, but I don't found nothing more that it

EDIT 3

With ebassi ideia about, g_signal_query is what I need. I do this for abstract:

1 - query the params of signal with g_signal_query, set into my structure to pass with callback user_data
2 - connect with g_cclosure_new_swap and g_signal_connect_closure, this set gpointer user_data as first param
3 - created callback like this: `connect_callback(gpointer user_data, ...)`, with variable parameter list
4 - inside callback, get back my struct with custom + g_signal_query result
5 - loop into param_types of GSignalQuery, verifying each fundamental types
6 - get va_arg with correct type

Complete code for call the callback

```
    // Create gpoint param
    struct st_callback *callback_object = (struct st_callback *)malloc(sizeof(struct st_callback));
    memset(callback_object, 0, sizeof(struct st_callback));

    callback_object->callback_name = callback_name;
    callback_object->callback_params = callback_params;

    // Get params of signal
    GSignalQuery signal_info;
    g_signal_query(g_signal_lookup (callback_signal, G_OBJECT_TYPE (instance)), &signal_info);

    // Save 
    callback_object->signal_id = signal_info.signal_id;
    callback_object->signal_name = signal_info.signal_name;
    callback_object->itype = signal_info.itype;
    callback_object->signal_flags = signal_info.signal_flags;
    callback_object->return_type = signal_info.return_type;
    callback_object->n_params = signal_info.n_params;
    callback_object->param_types = signal_info.param_types;

    GClosure  *closure;
    closure = g_cclosure_new_swap (G_CALLBACK (connect_callback), callback_object, NULL);
    int ret = g_signal_connect_closure (instance, callback_event, closure, TRUE);
```

And the callback

```
static bool connect_callback(gpointer user_data, ...)
{
    // Return to st_callback
    struct st_callback *callback_object = (struct st_callback *) user_data;

    // get parameters count
    int param_count = callback_object->n_params;
    va_list ap;
    va_start(ap, param_count);

    // loop paramters
    for (int i=0; i<param_count; i++) {

        switch (G_TYPE_FUNDAMENTAL(callback_object->param_types[i])) {
            case G_TYPE_CHAR:

                break;
            case G_TYPE_UCHAR:

                break;
            case G_TYPE_STRING:
            {
                char *path = va_arg(ap, char *);
                break;
            }
            case G_TYPE_OBJECT:

                break;
            case G_TYPE_POINTER:

                break;
            case G_TYPE_INTERFACE: 

                break;
            case G_TYPE_PARAM:

                break;
            case G_TYPE_BOXED:
            {
                // Example, try to cast correct boxed
                GdkEvent *e = va_arg(ap, GdkEvent *);

                break;
            }
        }
    }

    va_end(ap);
}
```

Needs to correct return and boxed cast, but with this I can work fine

Comment: Perhaps have your callback take a structure that contains all the possible properties or even a union.

Comment: But what are the correct way to do this verifications? what type of extra param and what param are my structure

Comment: I have never used the gtk library, but the C++ way to do this is to pass a functor, i.e. a class/struct that has `operator()` overloaded, and just invoke operator().  The parameters would already be set up as class members.

Comment: [See this example](https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/8100669d447d3d7c).  If this is what you are trying to achieve, I can post this as an answer.

Comment: It's a good example. But I need do more tests, because I dont think I can get G_TYPEs without rewrite all classes. But it's an idea. I need do more tests

Comment: Honestly, I don't think your issue is specific to gtk -- it sounds like a general C++ issue and how to solve it.  Try to attempt to explain the issue in higher terms (I have no idea what G_TYPE is all about).  If you did that (abstracted your question to a C++ one, and not a gtk one), then probably you will get more help from C++ programmers who know nothing about gtk, but are wizards at coming up with solutions to your issue using templates, meta programming, or similar code to what I linked to.

Comment: It's gtk issue, because I can cast param1 to GdkEvent. But I cannot get param1 type, bause it's a pointer, to cast to GdkEvent. If gtk has a method who pass the type for me, it's ok, but doesn't. in the first g_signal_connect, param1 is my struct, in the second, it's a GdkEvent. My problem is not a C++ issue, is how abstract user_function like gtk_signal_connect_full does in gtk2

Comment: Sorry: "because it's a gpointer (void *)"

Comment: *because I can cast param1 to GdkEvent. But I cannot get param1 type, bause it's a pointer, to cast to GdkEvent.* -- Seriously, how is what you described not a general C++ issue?  The types could be called "dog" or "cat", this issue can be described in higher-level terms than specifically mentioning gtk.  You have an API that takes a parameter which is probably a `void *` under the hood.  Thus it is not possible to know the type from a `void *` using C++ -- you need to have apriori knowledge of the type to do the appropriate cast.

Comment: If you passed an object with virtual function (as my example shows), you could always cast the type to a `base *` and invoke the virtual function.  That's why the `operator()` example worked in the example I posted.  The receiving function didn't know what the static type of the object was -- all it assumed was that the type was derived from `base`.

Comment: Ok Paul. But remember i'm not writing the class, and sometimes it's not a object, is a simple type, or its do not exists

Answer (score 2):

You should not use the same function for different types of callbacks. Some callbacks take different parameters, others have different return values — for instance, in your example, `clicked` does not return anything, whereas `button-press-event` returns a boolean value.

If you have common code that needs to be executed in different signal handlers, write a function and then call it from the various handlers.

Comment: In my real application, I'm planning configure signals from txt external file. User can add signal name line by line. So, I'll need test signal by signal?

Comment: Yes, you will need to check the signature of each signal. You can inspect the signal at run time and check the type of each argument and the return type, using the GSignal API: https://developer.gnome.org/gobject/stable/gobject-Signals.html#g-signal-query

Comment: ebassi, I think you kill my problem with the g_signal_query. I'll do some tests and return. Thank you for now

Comment: I edited my question, EDIT 3, with my soluctions with g_signal_query. Maybe you see my solution stranger, but works. Thanks for help me to know this method